# Is karate mock supports AVRO object testing?

Tags: avro, karate

Is karate mock supports AVRO object testing, because in my project I have a requirement to mock AVRO object?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but you just need to write some a utility to convert Avro <--> JSON (Or Java `Map`s) and you are done.

Please refer this thread: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/412#issuecomment-420690472